# Macro to copy columns from multiple workbooks to only one rearranging them side by side

Tags: vba, excel

Hi guys I have a small problem I need help with.

I am trying to copy data from multiple Workbook with the sheet called Auto1 into a master Workbook named Autos. From the multiple Workbooks I need the cell range H18:M3164.

Until here I found a macro that could help me, but then I need to rearrange the information side by side (For example the first workbook selected columns would be pasted in the first A:F columns of the "Autos" workbook, the second workbook selected columns would be pasted in the G:L columns and so on).

The code I have just copies and pastes it in the end so I'm asking if you could give me a hand.

Here is my code so far.

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub combine_data()
    '
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim SumPath As String
    Dim MyName As String
    Dim SumName As String
    Dim MyTemplate As String
    Dim SumTemplate As String
    Dim myWS As Worksheet
    Dim sumWS As Worksheet

    'Define folders and filenames
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\Teste\"
    SumPath = "C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\Teste\Master\"
    MyTemplate = "*.xls"  'Set the template.
    SumTemplate = "Autos.xlsx"

    'Open the template file and get the Worksheet to put the data into
    SumName = Dir(SumPath & SumTemplate)
    Workbooks.Open SumPath & SumName
    Set sumWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Open each source file, copying the data from each into the template file
    MyName = Dir(MyPath & MyTemplate)    'Retrieve the first file
    Do While MyName <> ""
        'Open the source file and get the worksheet with the data we want.
        Workbooks.Open MyPath & MyName
        Set myWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auto1")
        'Copy the data from the source and paste at the end of Summary sheet
        myWS.Range("H18:M3164").Copy
        sumWS.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 
     Paste:=xlPasteValues
         'Close the current sourcefile and get the next
         Workbooks(MyName).Close SaveChanges:=False        'close
          MyName = Dir                    'Get next file
     Loop
     'Now all sourcefiles are copied into the Template file. Close and save it
     Workbooks(SumName).Close SaveChanges:=True
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need to change the paste line. Below assumes you are pasting into row 1.

```
myWS.Range("H18:M3164").Copy
sumWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial
```

or to base it on the last used row in column A

```
Dim r As Long
'this line needs to go before the Do loop.
r =sumWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'these stay where they are 
myWS.Range("H18:M3164").Copy
sumWS.Cells(r, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlvalues
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, but just a question is there a way to choose where the information gets pasted, for example I want it pasted after row 16 since the data only comes after row 16 and the other lines before are the header with the information regarding the document. Sorry if I'm not being very clear but I thank you again for work

Comment: OK do you mean you want it pasted in row 17 then, or can the row vary? Have added some code above anyway which may do the trick.

Comment: The only thing that will vary is the column because what I want is the information of H18:M3164 from multiple workbooks side by side so it easier to compare and to work, but in addition I want to be able to control where the information starts to get pasted. The place I want it to star being pasted is the H19 of my sum template Autos.xlsx

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes I did, the code pasted the information in the B2:M3147 and I realized I also have a the problem where the information  in the cell isn't the number but the formula from where it came (=ROUND(D3118*#REF!;2)); I'm sorry if I'm not able to fully explain what I want, I'm not very good with coding